# How to change BorderBrush colour to default

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm trying to change the BorderBrush colour of a TextBox to the default value. After looking at the ControlTemplate, it seems that no default colour is specified. Any idea what the default colour is?

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to be the ControlTemplate.

I found numerous examples for the XAML, however I need this to be done in code-behind like so:

```
txtValue1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
```

Comment: I would like to add to my answer: There is no true correct default value, the template shows for BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" while this is a brush you will find lower on that page, it is the brush for one theme, so it might not be the same on different pcs, depending on the used windows version or more precisely the used theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly want the default value of the property, call

```
txtValue1.ClearValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty);
```

But this will change the property back to its initial value(in this case i would guess black or transparent). 
I'm not sure, but i guess you want the original color giving the currently used theme. So if you want local changes to be cleared, you can use [GetLocalValueEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getlocalvalueenumerator.aspx) and query for all local set properties and find the property where you want to clear the value. But if you have a custom style on the element you are using and you want to revert one property out of that, i don't think thats easily possible.

For that matter, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) is an important read.